# How to access other data of foreign key and call them on frontend in django

Tags: html, django, for-loop, django-queryset

I have to models Customers and Purchase_order. I am taking customer as a foreign key in purchase invoice and fetching data..

My data is like this:

```
    {'id': 5, 'purchase_number': 'TES-PO-1', 'purchase_date': datetime.date(2022, 9, 1), 'customer_id_id': 1, 'special_instructions': '', 'total': '70', 'discount': 2.578125, 'round_off': '77.5', 'grand_total': '78', 'user_id': 1, 'remarks': '', 'company_id': 1}
 {'id': 6, 'purchase_number': 'TES-PO-2', 'purchase_date': datetime.date(2022, 9, 6), 'customer_id_id': 2, 'special_instructions': '', 'total': '24', 'discount': 0.75, 'round_off': '28.5', 'grand_total': '29', 'user_id': 1, 'remarks': '', 'company_id': 1}
    Action
```

here I am getting customer id as 1,2,3 its pk value but I wish to call its customer_company there.. how can I access them by its id on frontend?

want to show name instead of ID

[image]

views.py

```
def get_sales_invoices(request):
company_label= Company_Setup.objects.get(id=request.session['company_id'])
invoices=Sales_Invoice.objects.filter(company=company_label).all().values()

customer_data=[]
for c in invoices:
    cust_id=c['customer_id_id']
    customers_details= Customer.objects.filter(id=cust_id).all().values()
    customer_data.append(customers_details)
return render(request,"sales/list_sales_invoice.html",{'invoices':invoices, 'customer_data':customer_data})
```

customer/models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):

customer_id = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=50)
customer_company = models.CharField(max_length=50,default=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=TITLE_CHOICES, default="NA")


first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=True)
middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=True)
surname = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=True)

company= models.ForeignKey(Company_Setup,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=True)

city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
pin = models.CharField(max_length=50)

country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
country_code=models.CharField(max_length=50)

customer_address = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=True)
contact_person_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
website= models.CharField(max_length=50, default="NA")

GST = models.CharField(max_length=50)
bill_to = models.CharField(max_length=50)
ship_to = models.CharField(max_length=50)

payment_method =  models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=PAYMENT_CHOICES, default="Normal")

terms = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=TERMS_CHOICES, default="NA")

deffered= models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=DEFERRED_CHOICES, default="NA")


def __str__(self):
    return self.customer_company
```

purchase/model

```
class Purchase_Order(models.Model):
    purchase_number=models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=50,default=True)
    purchase_date=models.DateField()
    supplier=models.ForeignKey(Supplier,on_delete=models.CASCADE) #Foreign key
    special_instructions=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    total=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    discount=models.FloatField(max_length=50,default=0)
    round_off=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    grand_total=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user =models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    remarks=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    company=models.ForeignKey(Company_Setup,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked on me
views.py

@login_required(login_url='/login')
def get_sales_invoices(request):
company_label= Company_Setup.objects.get(id=request.session['company_id'])
invoices=Sales_Invoice.objects.filter(company=company_label).all()

```
invoice_list = [[i.customer_id.customer_company, i.invoice_number, i.invoice_date, i.grand_total,i.id] for i in invoices]
response = invoice_list


return render(request,"sales/list_sales_invoice.html",{'invoices':invoices, 'customer_data':response})
```

html

```
<tbody id="rows">
                            {% if customer_data %}
                            {% for i in customer_data %}
                           
                            <tr>
                                <td><a class='bx bxs-edit' style="text-decoration:None"
                                        href="/sales/update/{{i.4}}"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <a class="fas fa-eye" href="/sales/sales-invoice-pdf/{{i.4}}">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <a href="/sales/delete/{{i.4}}" class="bx bxs-trash-alt" href=""></a>
                                </td>
                                <th>{{i.2}}</th>
                                <th>{{i.1}}</th>
                                <th>{{i.0}}</th>
                                <th>{{i.3}}</th>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
                        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the customer object `customer = Customer.objects.get(pk=customer_ID)` then access the name field of Customer model by `name = customer.name`

Answer (score 0):

==== I have two models In AddmitatonModel has foreign key of StudentModel ====

```
class StudentModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    roll = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class AddmissionModel(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(StudentModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.student.name)
```

======== in view.py =========

```
def DemoView(request):
    all_students = AddmissionModel.objects.all()
    context = {'all_students':all_students}
    return render(request,'demo.html',context)
```

====== in html file itrated all student detail using foreigenkey ======

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid;">
                <th>No.</th>
                <th>Student name</th>
                <th>Student Roll</th>
                <th>Student Email</th>
                <th>Student City</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

            {% for i in all_students %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
                <td>{{i.student.name}}</td>
                <td>{{i.student.roll}}</td>
                <td>{{i.student.email}}</td>
                <td>{{i.student.city}}</td>
                <td>{{i.status}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

======== Webpage output =============

[image]

Comment: not working .. I am working with queryset

Comment: Please send me  your view.py code

Comment: updated in my question please check

Comment: please send me customer model

Comment: updated in question please check

Comment: customers_details= Customer.objects.filter(id=cust_id).all().values("first_name")

try this if not working msg me

Comment: you not getting me the condition is working bug when I trying to fetch data on frontent its showing me double values

Comment: because I am using for loop there

Comment: Use value_list instead of values

Comment: If still not working then                
U can connect with me on anydesk